# How to get a console to read through all conditions

Tags: c#, if-statement, console, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

I have a console application that asks the user to choose one of three options and to be able to open an inventory if desired.  However, instead of checking to see if any of the other conditions are true are false, the console just reads the conditions linearly and waits till the first one has been satisfied. So for example, in the code below, it runs the first bit of text, presents the options, and then waits for the user to enter "inventory" without considering the other options.  What's up? Why does this happen? and how do I get the console to run through and check whether or not all conditions have been satisfied?

Here's the code

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Feed_de_monky
{
    class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        string one = "";
        string two = "";
        string inventory = "inventory";
        int storyint = 0;
        TextReader input = Console.In;
        TextWriter output = Console.Out;
        int options = 0;

        if (storyint == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are in a dark Jungle.  You look into the darkness of the trees and see the silhouette of a tiger standing in front of you down the way.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("turn and run");
            Console.WriteLine("pounce on tiger");
            Console.WriteLine("climb a tree.");
            options++;

            if (input.ReadLine() == inventory)
            {
                output.WriteLine(one);
                output.WriteLine(two);
                return;
            }

            else if(input.ReadLine() == "turn and run" && options == 1)
            {
                output.WriteLine("");
                output.WriteLine("The tiger chases you through the darkness.  You never had a chance.");
                Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }

            else if(input.ReadLine() == "pounce on tiger" && options == 1)
            {
                output.WriteLine("");
                output.WriteLine("The tiger is caught by surprise.  You overwhelm the beast and he dies of shock and surprise on the spot");
                one = "tiger skin";
                output.WriteLine("TIGER SKIN ADDED TO YOUR INVENTORY");
                storyint++;
                options++;
            }

            else if(input.ReadLine() == "climb a tree" && options == 1)
            {
                output.WriteLine("");
                output.WriteLine("You climb the tree.  But while you sit on the branches believing yourself to be safe, the tiger jumps through the air and bites your head clean off.  You never had a chance.");
                Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: is it because options != 1

Comment: is " climb a tree. "  always the last output before the issue?

Comment: You should only call `ReadLine()` once, then test that result in all your `if/else` values. As it stands, the first `if` condition executes and reads a line. If you didn't enter "inventory", then the next `else if` executes and reads another line. Now if you enter anything except "turn and run", the next `else if` will read a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to set

```
var inputLine = input.ReadLine();
```

And then do your logic on the variable inputLine.

As you have it now I believe it will call ReadLine more times than you are expecting.  But if you just call .ReadLine() one time and assign it to a variable that should act better than calling it repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks.  You were right.  I added your line into the if(storyint == 0){} and it worked perfectly.